# How to keep user signed in once user has entered google+ account credentials in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, google-plus, access-token

I have integrated Google+ iOS SDK in an iPhone application.
I want to keep user signed in once user has entered account details.
The problem is that if application is terminated and opened again, user is signed out and I need to ask user to sign in.
Is there any way to store something like access token and use it instead of presenting sign in screen? or is it because Google itself sign out the user on application termination?

Comment: I think that you are doing something wrong with the integration because Google-plus performs `silent login` automatically. So please check again the steps required for the Google-plus integration.

Comment: @danypata Are you sure that Google does silent login when app is opened after termination?

Comment: Please check the https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in, for the `Automatically sign in the user` section.

Comment: @danypata I did the google+ integration again from scratch. Still, same problem persists. `keychain` is somehow removed  and that is why `trySilentAuthentication` method does not work.

Comment: I have a better solution for it. I have implemented it in my app. If you logged in once then google plus automatically keep your account detail until unless you delete your app or logout from app.

Comment: @chandan So what do you think is the solution of my question?

Comment: let me give an answer for your question. Wait for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, making `GPPSignIn` object global solved the problem.

Here is how to do that : 
In `Supporting Files` folder->`appname-Prefix.pch` file , add following lines :

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
GPPSignIn * signIn;
```

Below this lines :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Comment: That is a bit grim - GPPSignIn has a singleton by default, you should be using [GPPSignIn sharedInstance]. How were you managing the sign in  object (e.g. configuration and so on)?

Comment: `[GPPSignIn sharedInstance];` is to create an object. My above code is to declare `GPPSignIn` reference globally. That was solution to MY problem.

Comment: shareInstance only creates the object the first time - after that it is a globally referencable handle to that same object. You could still have the GooglePlus header in your PCH, but you wouldn't need the global object. But, either way works I guess! :)

Comment: @Geek Will this be working after Application get crashed? What will happen if application get crashed?

Answer (score 1):

Current version of solution of this issue with iOS 9, xcode 7.0.1 is

```
(void) signInSilently
```

call it with **GIDSignIn** object reference.

As provided by google:
Attempts to sign in a previously authenticated user without interaction.
[Reference Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in)

In response it will be return to

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
 withError:(NSError *)error{}
```

If user expired or loged-out then **(GIDGoogleUser *)user** will be **nill** and detail will be with **(NSError *)error** and vice versa in case of loged-in user.

Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

For Google+ login . Here is few steps as follows

1.> Firstly add Google+ SDK and [create Google plus client id](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) under click on "API Access pane"

insert **GoogleOpenSource.framework**,**GooglePlus.bundle**,**GooglePlus.framework**

2.> Now globally assign a macro for `ClientID` like that

```
 #define kClientID  @"//paas client id which your app provided by developer account portal";
```

3.> Implement it in your `AppDelegate.h` file

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

extern NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,GPPDeepLinkDelegate>
{

}
-(void)clearApplicationCaches;
```

4.> Implement it in your `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
    [GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];
    [GPPDeepLink readDeepLinkAfterInstall];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveDeepLink:(GPPDeepLink *)deepLink
{

}

#pragma mark - Memory management methods
-(void)clearApplicationCaches
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self clearApplicationCaches];
}

- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation 
{
   return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

**Tip:** If you wish to test up to this point, you can call `[signIn authenticate]` at the end of your `viewDidLoad` method. The application will redirect you to a sign-in dialog at startup

5.> Now go to your view controller and in `yourViewController.h` file

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

@class GPPSignInButton;

@interface yourViewController:UIViewController <GPPSignInDelegate>
{
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton;
```

Synthesize the `GPPSignInButton` property if necessary, although this step should no longer be required in newer versions of Xcode.

```
@synthesize signInButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [GPPSignInButton class];

  GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
  signIn.clientID = kClientID;
  signIn.delegate = self;

  [signIn trySilentAuthentication]; /// this calls finishedWithAuth automatically
}
```

Add the `GPPSignInButton` to your storyboard, XIB file, or instantiate it programmatically. `GPPSignInButton` inherits from `UIButton`, so if you are using a storyboard or XIB file, you can drag a Round Rect Button or View onto your view controller and set its Custom Class to `GPPSignInButton`.

Connect the button it to the `signInButton` property of your view controller.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - GooglePluseDelegate Implementation

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error
{

    NSLog(@"email %@ ",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email: %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail]);
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);

    // 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

    // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
    [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];


    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"]; 

    // *4. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.*
    plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";


    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] animated:TRUE];
                    if (error) {
                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alertView show];
                    }
                } else
                {
                    NSLog(@"userId = %@",query.activityId);

                    NSLog(@"person = %@",[person.name.familyName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",person.name.givenName]);

                    NSLog(@"person = %@", person);
                    NSDictionary *tempDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail,@"email",person.identifier,@"googleID",[person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",person.name.familyName],@"name",[person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",person.name.familyName],@"username",person.gender,@"gender", nil];


               [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parsingLoginWithGoogleApi:) toTarget:self withObject:tempDic]; 
                }
            }];
}

// ---- its call a web service to login with google+ info
-(void) parsingLoginWithGoogleApi:(NSDictionary*) googleUserInfoDic
{

    NSLog(@"google User Info Dic = %@", googleUserInfoDic );
    NSString *name = @"";
    NSString *username = @"";
    NSString *emailId = @"";
    NSString *gender = @"";
    NSString *apiURLStr =@"";
    if ([DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"isLogin"])
    {
        name =[DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"g_name"];
        emailId =[DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"g_emailId"];
        username =[DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"g_username"];
        gender =[DEFAULTS objectForKey:@"g_gender"];


        apiURLStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@google_login/%@/%@/%@/%@",SiteAPIURL,emailId,[name stringByURLEncode],[username stringByURLEncode],gender];
    }
    else
    {
        name =[googleUserInfoDic valueForKey:@"name"];
        username =[googleUserInfoDic valueForKey:@"username"];
        emailId = @"0";
        if ([googleUserInfoDic valueForKey:@"email"])
            emailId=[googleUserInfoDic valueForKey:@"email"];

        gender = @"0";
        if ([googleUserInfoDic valueForKey:@"gender"])
            gender =[googleUserInfoDic valueForKey:@"gender"];

        apiURLStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@google_login/%@/%@/%@/%@",SiteAPIURL,emailId,[name stringByURLEncode],[username stringByURLEncode],gender];
    }

    NSLog(@"login Google apiURLStr==>>>%@",apiURLStr);

    NSString *outputStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURLStr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"login Google response==>>>%@",outputStr);

    if (outputStr == NULL)
    {
        NSDictionary *infoDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"There was a small problem",@"title",@"The network doesn't seem to be responding, please try again.",@"message",@"OK",@"cancel",@"1",@"tag",self,@"delegate", nil];
        [CommonFunctions performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertWithInfo:) withObject:infoDic waitUntilDone:NO];

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] animated:TRUE];
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [outputStr JSONValue];

        if (jsonResponse != nil)
        {
            NSString *replycode=[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"replyCode"];

            if ([replycode isEqualToString:@"success"])
            {
                NSUserDefaults *userDefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [userDefs setObject:name forKey:@"g_name"];
                [userDefs setObject:emailId forKey:@"g_emailId"];
                [userDefs setObject:username forKey:@"g_username"];
                [userDefs setObject:gender forKey:@"g_gender"];

                [userDefs setObject:[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"sesId"] forKey:@"sessionId"];
                sessionId = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"sesId"];
                [userDefs setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
                [userDefs setObject:[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"userId"] forKey:@"userId"];
                [userDefs setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"isLogin"];
                [userDefs setObject:@"Google" forKey:@"LoginType"];
                userId = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"userId"];
                [userDefs synchronize];

                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] animated:TRUE];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushProfileVC:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] waitUntilDone:NO];
            }
            else
            {
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] animated:TRUE];

                NSDictionary *infoDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:replycode,@"title",[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"replyMsg"],@"message",@"OK",@"cancel",@"1",@"tag",nil,@"delegate", nil];
                [CommonFunctions performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertWithInfo:) withObject:infoDic waitUntilDone:NO];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] animated:TRUE];

            NSDictionary *infoDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"There was a small problem",@"title",@"The network doesn't seem to be responding, please try again.",@"message",@"OK",@"cancel",@"1",@"tag",self,@"delegate", nil];
            [CommonFunctions performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertWithInfo:) withObject:infoDic waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I have integrated gogle+ sdk. I know how to login user. My problem is that once app is closed and opened again then user is no longer signed in. I don't want this to happen unless user logs out explicitly.

Comment: Hi Akash , yesterday i forgot to send parsingLoginWithGoogleApi method. So please have a look on my updated code and see how i store all the values fetch through Google+. So you don't need to Login fetch it again and again. Thanks

Comment: What is `SiteAPIURL` in `apiURLStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@google_login/%@/%@/%@/%@",SiteAPIURL,emailId,[name stringByURLEncode],[username stringByURLEncode],gender];`?

Comment: SiteAPIURL is your webservice url like NSString *SiteAPIURL= @"http://yourLoginUrl/";... When you call any webservice via calling parsingLoginWithGoogleApi method then You can store your Google+ info inside it's method body like as i m doing and can use it further anywhere. Then u just need to click on your google+button it will call finishedWithAuth and which will automatically call parsingLoginWithGoogleApi where you can check any thing

Comment: [signIn trySilentAuthentication]; add this line at the end of your viewDidLoad method . It will automatically call "finishedWithAuth" method and fetch your data whenever you launch your app

Comment: Hi akash patel, have you implemented it ?

Comment: Hi i have implemented and tested it at my end and it's working fine. please have a look on my updated code and implement [signIn trySilentAuthentication];  This is responsible for keep every time login